# Solve $y' = -x, x'' = y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution $(x(t),y(t))$ of the system
> $$\begin{cases}
> y'(t) + x(t) = 0 \\
> x''(t) - y(t) = 0
> \end{cases}
> $$

It can be easily observed that $$(Ae^{-t}, Ae^{-t})$$
is a solution for any constant $A$. But as $x''$ exists there must be another solution out there. As I am new to this type of problem, how should I proceed?

Comment: HAve you tried to solve $x'''(t)+x(t)=0$? (cf [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients))

Comment: @TitoEliatron I got $$x(t) = Ae^{-t} + Be^{(-1+\sqrt{3}i)t/2} + Ce^{(-1-\sqrt{3}i)t/2} $$ so should I now take $x''$ to get $y$?

Comment: Yes, for example

Comment: @macton I think it should be $(1\pm i \sqrt{3})/2,$ not $(-1\pm i \sqrt 3)/2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's correct, my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second equation, we have $y' = x'''$.

We substitute the first equation

$$x''' + x = 0$$

Solving this leads to

$$x(t) =  c_1 e^{-t}+c_3 e^{t/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)+c_2 e^{t/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)$$

From the second equation, we know $y = x''$, so just take the second derivative of $x(t)$ to find $y(t)$.